# How can I get the Solidify modifier to apply after a texture displacement?

Tags: texturing, modifiers

I'm working on the center cup part of a daffodil, and this is my current setup. I have textures that are mapped such that they displace the geometry the way I want it. I then have a Solidify modifier to prevent the mesh from being "single-sided". This is the result:

[image: Current Result]

However, the problem I'm having is that the textures seems to displace the geometry *after* the Solidify modifier has been applied, but I want the textures to displace the geometry *before* the Solidify modifier. I know there's a Displace modifier, but that doesn't give me the fine-tuning control I need and have within the Texture panel. As the textures displace according to the normal, the result is that the edge is thick when I want it to have the same thickness as the rest.

How can I force the Solidify modifier to take place *last*? Is there another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: What exactly can't you do with displace modifier that you can do with the texture panel? as far as I know, the displace modifier can use any texture made in the texture panel..

Comment: @gandalf3: In the texture panel, I've set the projection to Tube, the mapping is X: X, Y: Y, Z: None, and on the X-axis, the texture repeats 6 times.

Comment: I see.. you could use three different displace modifiers (one each fore X, Y, and Z) and the displace _does_ seem to take into account the repeating.  
As far as I know, there is no way to do this with the Texture panel displace, as the displacement is done at rendertime on the already solidified mesh.

Comment: @gandalf3: Just tried that. Doesn't work. The entire mesh moves in one direction or the other, which indicates that it's being applied uniformly in one direction, despite the fact that I set texture coordinates to UV. Also, using the Displace modifier doesn't allow me to use the multiple-output feature of texture nodes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Displace Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html#displace-modifier)

Using this modifier before Solidify is the easiest option.

[image: Displace modifier example]

Since you seem to have tried this, I'll include the [blend file for you to inspect](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/22646).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "Material Index Offset" setting of the Solidify modifier to apply a material with a inverted displacement to the generated faces.

[image: Example setup]