# How to add thickness to transparent material from image?

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes

I have this object with a material I created with an image, how can I manage to add thickness to it ? I already tried adding the solidify modifier but could not get any result...
[image: my object]

Here is a screenshot from Blender, as you can see the object is totally flat. How can I give it some thickness ?

Thanks,

Edit: Here are screenshots with "Only Rim" checked and not checked to give a better idea of what I get but is not good

[image]
[image]

Comment: Solidify modifier is made for this, if it doesn't work try applying object Scale first (CTRL+A). Switch to solid view for this, perhaps the geometry is there but you can't see it in rendered view.

Comment: With solidify I can only have like two thin "layers" and not a thick one

Comment: Is "Fill rim" checked? It should be by default. Please post more screenshots if you want accurate help.

Comment: Yes it is, I tried with it checked and not checked

Comment: the solidify modifier is made to "solidify" mesh only: you cannot extrude a texture (it would create confusion for fractional alpha values)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/is-it-possible-to-give-a-texture-thickness https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45415/adding-thickness-to-a-3d-textured-plane-in-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84129/is-there-a-way-to-add-fake-thickness-to-an-alpha-image-texture

Comment: I really can't get anything good from those three links... Maybe someone would have an idea to create a real 3D object looking like this ?